# How to let other pc to access my php pages using my pc as a server?

Tags: php, linux, apache, fedora

I have a LAMP (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP) configuration on my Linux fedora 20. I have created a localhost website. What i want to know is that, is there exist any procedure by which i can make my pc as main-server and other pc as client-server so that other pc can access my php code on his/her machine and can put data into my pc database. What i want is, other pc should has a remote access to my php pages. I know its possible and definitely it can be done. But I don't know how. I will be grateful if anyone answer.

Comment: What do you mean? You want other pc to be able to browse your web app ?

Comment: If your web server is bound to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` only it's just a matter of asking others on your local network to connect to whatever IP address your computer has. Make sure your firewall allows access on port 80 incoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access site/server using machine, IP-ADDRESS.

Apache requests may blocked on the firewall. The following commands were run to allow all requests through the firewall;

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80

firewall-cmd --reload
```

It should also be possible to use the following command instead of allowing port 80;

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=http

firewall-cmd --reload
```